# jQuery fadeIn Messing up #hashtag Cross-linking

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, debugging

Ok, so I have a whole page hide / fadeIn effect happening with jQuery.  Everything was working smoothly until I realized that the `delay()` + `fadeIn()` is causing my

`<a href="http://example.com/my_page/#my_ID">Hashtag Links</a>`

to load with the scroll position at the top rather than where that `#my_ID` is on the page.

I know this is related to the whole page `delay()` // `fadeIn()` effects.  It's not an option for me to ditch these effects, any way to circumvent this problem?

You can view the site (in production) at

http://valeriaentertainment.com.s66112.gridserver.com/

**EDIT**

This is the relevant jQuery code:

```
// #curtain DIV begins hidden then fades in after #bgImage (curtain) is loaded - prevents "ribbon" loading effect in Chrome

var allDone = false;
var url = $('.bgImage').attr('src');
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  if (!allDone) {
    $('#curtain').delay(1500).fadeIn(1000);
    allDone = true;
  }
};
setTimeout(img.onload, 2000); // show the hidden stuff after 5 seconds, image or no image
img.src = url;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance at a [gallery page](http://valeriaentertainment.com.s66112.gridserver.com/gallery/#variety), it looks like the entire page content is initially hidden. When the browser is loading the page, it will start looking for the element identified in the URL fragment; that element will be hidden or not visible and hence it won't have any useful position to scroll to and nothing happens to the scroll position.

I think the easiest thing to do would be to handle the scrolling yourself in the [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn) callback:

- Grab the fragment out of `window.location.hash`.
- Find out where it is on the page with something like:
  `var y = $('#' + window.location.hash).offset().top;`
- Then scroll the page to that position:
  `$('html,body').attr('scrollTop', y);`

You could even animate the `scrollTop` change if you wanted to get fancy.

Here's an example to get you started:

```
$('#curtain').delay(1500).fadeIn(1000, function() {
    // Bail out if there is no hash.
    if(!window.location.hash)
        return;

    // Convert the hash to an element and bail out
    // if there is no such element.
    var $e = $(window.location.hash);
    if($e.length < 1)
        return;

    // And, finally, do what we're here to do.
    $('html,body').attr('scrollTop', $e.offset().top);
});
```

If you wanted to [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) the scrolling then you'd change the `$('html,body').attr(...)` part to something like this:

```
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: '+=' + $e.offset().top }, 'fast');
```

Comment: thank you!  I've posted the relevant jQuery code in an edit to my question - can you tell me what your suggestion would look like in context?  Forgive me, I'm a javascript n00b :(

Comment: @Brian: I added a sample implementation for you.